# Push and read inside and from nested arrays and ng-repeat them

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**UPDATE 2: [forked plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YN7402B0xGsZLvdYPwKp?p=preview), it works.**

---

**UPDATE: [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/de2TWTTuUcpWdFKU0IP8?p=preview)**

---

I'm trying to place an order inside an array, and display its items (and how many of them), but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I just can't access the list of `pizzas` inside `orderList` with ng-repeat.

What my code should do is:

- read the menu stored inside an array
- click an item to store it inside another array
- if it's the first time that is being stored, assign `n=1` to that element
- else `n+=1`
- display your order reading `pizza.name` and `pizza.n` from `orderList`
- remove items stored in `orderList`

code.javascript

```
$scope.orderList = [];

$scope.add = function(pizza) {
  var n;
  $scope.placeholder = 'Aggiungi altro?';
  if ($scope.orderList.indexOf(pizza) === -1) {
    $scope.orderList.pizza = [];
    n = 1;
    return $scope.orderList.pizza.push(pizza.name, n);
  } else {
    return $scope.orderList.pizza.n += 1;
  }
};

$scope.remove = function(pizza) {
  var index;
  index = $scope.orderList.indexOf(pizza);
  $scope.orderList.pizza.splice(index, 1);
  if ($scope.orderList.length === 0) {
    return $scope.example();
  }
};
```

form.html

```
<ul ng-hide="list" class="list">
  <li ng-repeat="pizza in pizze | filter:search | orderBy: 'name'">
    <button ng-click="add(pizza)" class="add">{{pizza.name}}<br>{{pizza.ingredients}}</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul ng-hide="order" class="list">
  <li ng-repeat="pizza in orderList">
    <button ng-click="remove()" class="add">Rimuovi {{pizza.name + ' x' + pizza.n}}</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is all messy. You are trying to use object property on an array. `$scope.orderList` is array ... it has no property `pizza` as in `$scope.orderList.pizza`

Comment: So what would be the right way to do it?

Comment: I think what you want is just `pizza.n = (pizza.n || 0 ) +1`

Comment: Oh yes, that is better. But that code still doesn't display all pizza arrays stored inside orderList (pizza.name and its related pizza.n for each pizza)

Comment: You need to push the pizza to the array if it's not there. if it's already there just updated the count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be able to simplify this down to

```
$scope.add = function(pizza) {
  pizza.n = (pizza.n || 0) +1; // count updates regardless if in array or not
  if ($scope.orderList.indexOf(pizza) === -1) {    
    $scope.orderList.push(pizza);    
  }// if already in array nothing to do
};

$scope.remove = function(pizza) {
  pizza.n = null;// just in case user puts it back into order
  var index = $scope.orderList.indexOf(pizza);
  if(index === -1) return;
  $scope.orderList.splice(index, 1);
  if (!$scope.orderList.length ) {
     $scope.example();
  }
};
```

Comment: It works! Now I'm doing a plnkr, need some more help for the `remove` function :D

Comment: You didn't use all of my code. Seems to work fine when you do http://plnkr.co/edit/sPe9OYbBFoHKnYA3aN2K?p=preview

Comment: Ooo but if order is more than one not sure what to do. Probably want to just do `pizza.n-1` if it is more than one and not splice array. Example click on `Porcini` 2 or 3 times so `n=2 or 3`

Comment: Solved, I'm just an idiot :D in my code there was `orderList.pizza.splice` rather than `orderList.splice`

Comment: One last thing: why does a function that empties `orderList`, keeps `orderList.pizza.n`? If I click on `order`, and then I do another order list, it keeps it. [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3HZqV8drXGpANWE4hgHN?p=preview)

Comment: Need to go through the order list and reset them all before you do `$scope.orderlist=[]`. I suggest you use `angular.copy` for the order

Comment: But.. if `pizza.n` is stored inside `orderList`, and I even `.splice(0,orderList.length)` it, why do I need to reset them all?

Comment: All the array elements are references to same object. So if same object is in multiple arrays changing it in one array changes all. So if you empty the orderList ...the original list still has `n`

Comment: No wait I think we're not understanding each other. You said I have to reset each pizza.n, but I said that doing that is not necessary if I drop the entire orderList array (but it seems something is wrong in my code because it isn't dropping it)

Comment: Look at data showing in view. http://plnkr.co/edit/rlRkbyEkLbsA4WqjGGMB?p=preview

Comment: Uhm.. after you click on order, click again in the search bar: why and where does it stores `pizza.n`?

Comment: Got it! It stores pizza.n two times! Think I need to change variable names.

Comment: No..it is the same object being referenced in more than one place. So when you empty orderList the original objects in `pizze` are not being reset

Comment: Damn.. so how do I not let `pizza.n` being stored in `$scope.pizze`?

Comment: Simplest might be copy orderList to `finalOrder`. Then...before empty orderList ...loop through it and reset `n`. Use `angular.copy`

Comment: No, the problem is that when `$scope.pizza` acquires `pizza.n`, when I click on order and then on the search bar, `{{pizza.n + ' ' + pizza.name}}` has not been reset because `pizza.n` is now stored in `$scope.pizze`

Comment: right... so easy fix is `orderList.forEach(function(item){item.n=0})` after you copy orderList to something like `finalOrder`. Then do `orderList=[]`

Comment: Uhm no, I need to remove that pizza.n, rather than set it to 0. [I can't](http://plnkr.co/edit/28Fo6AnC5Z0iM8blcFxl?p=preview)

Comment: then just do `delete item.n` in loop i showed above...no index needed

Answer (score 0):

Your code should actualy be something like this (this will actualy need some testing as i don't have the whole code) :

```
$scope.orderList = [];

$scope.add = function(pizza) {
    var n;
    $scope.placeholder = 'Aggiungi altro?';
    var index = $scope.orderList.map(function(item) {return item.name; }).indexOf(pizza.name);

    if (index != -1) {
        var n = 1;
        $scope.orderList[index] = {'n': n, 'name': pizza.name};

        return n;
    } 
    else {
         return $scope.orderList[index].n++;
    }
};

$scope.remove = function(pizzaName) {
     var index = $scope.orderList.map(function(item) {return item.name; }).indexOf(pizzaName);
    if(index != -1) {
        $scope.orderList.splice(index, 1);
    }
    return $scope.example();
};
```

And the html :

```
<ul ng-hide="list" class="list">
  <li ng-repeat="pizza in pizze | filter:search | orderBy: 'name'">
    <button ng-click="add(pizza)" class="add">{{pizza.name}}<br>{{pizza.ingredients}}</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul ng-hide="order" class="list">
  <li ng-repeat="pizza in orderList">
    <button ng-click="remove(pizza.name)" class="add">Rimuovi {{pizza.name + ' x' + pizza.n}}</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Same as my comment above.. `orderlist` is array, not object. Best to keep it as array also

Comment: Why would you make it an object? Now that requires rework in view , can't be ordered and requires changing the remove logic also. Simpler to stay with array

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle so that we can test withe your whole code?