# Data no longer being pushed inside an array after moving another (related) array into a .json

Tags: angularjs, json

I had [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/3xX7Sb2x15tguLPOhud8?p=preview) plnkr, working with an array. It had [some problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35779556/push-and-read-inside-and-from-nested-arrays-and-ng-repeat-them/) (data being pushed into two arrays), but it was doing its job. Now I moved that array into a .json, and `pizze.n` is no longer being pushed into `$scope.pizze` nor `$scope.orderList`. I guess at this point a good solution would be to create a second .json and use it as my new `orderList`, or am I wrong? By the way, how do I do it or a better solution? Here's the updated code.

```
app.factory('elencoPizze', function($http) {
  return {
    getdata: function() {
      return $http.get('json/pizze.json');
    }
  };
});

app.controller('showcaseCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, elencoPizze) {
  $scope.pizze = [];
  elencoPizze.getdata().success(function(data) {
    $scope.pizze = data;
  });
  return;
  $scope.orderList = [];
  $scope.add = function(pizza) {
    $scope.placeholder = 'Aggiungi altro?';
    $scope.empty = false;
    if ($scope.orderList.indexOf(pizza) === -1) {
      pizza.n = 1;
      return $scope.orderList.push(pizza);
    } else {
      return pizza.n += 1;
    }
  };
  return $scope.remove = function(pizza) {
    var lastRemoving;
    if (pizza.n <= 1) {
      pizza.n = 0;
      lastRemoving = function() {
        return $timeout((function() {
          var index;
          pizza.n = '';
          index = $scope.orderList.indexOf(pizza);
          $scope.orderList.splice(index, 1);
          if ($scope.orderList.length === 0) {
            $scope.example();
            return $scope.empty = true;
          }
        }), 300);
      };
      return lastRemoving();
    } else {
      return pizza.n -= 1;
    }
  };
});

// ---
// generated by coffee-script 1.9.2
```

Comment: try this plunker if it works for you, http://plnkr.co/edit/7ZehpXc4aSzUsNybigxe?p=preview

Comment: Well, maybe I didn't explain correctly: the plnkr mentioned above isn't the code I'm using now, now I've updated it with the code in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't returned a promise from your factory. Change to:

```
return {
    getdata: function() {
        return $http.get('json/pizze.json').then(function(data) {
            return data;
        })
    }
};
```

Comment: `TypeError: elencoPizze.getdata(...).success is not a function`

Comment: Changed `.then` to `.success` but `$scope.orderList` still isn't being updated

Comment: I noticed that I just can't access to `$scope.orderList`. If I populate if with some data and call it somewhere with `{{orderList + 'test'}}` I get just 'test'

Comment: You'll have to create a plunker.

Comment: Whops, solved. A wild `return` at line 6 of the code in the post.